# Unknown size of array in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I need to get a string input from user but i don't know the size of the string he would enter and i need to prepare an array in the memory as the size of the string because I'm using the interrupt 21h, ah=0ah.
So my question is how to get an input of string if I don't know the size of it?
Is there any other interrupt I can use? I searched but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I assume you mean `ah=0ah`, because `ah=9` is for output. Anyway, typically you would have _some_ upper limit on how much input to read, even if it's 1000, or 10000, or 100000 characters. If your upper limit is 255 characters or less you can use int 21h / ah=0ah. If it's higher than that I suppose you could write a loop where you read single characters with int 21h / ah=8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a buffer with a fixed size and use a loop with [the interrupt 21h, ah=8](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah08) for direct character input.

That way you can check how many bytes the user enters and terminate if this number exceeds your buffer size.

In short:

- create a buffer with a sufficient size
- grab a single char until

  - it is a linebreak
  - the number of entered chars will exceed your buffer
- do not forget to zero terminate your string

And if you really need to read the whole string you can maybe find a way to reallocate your buffer dynamically.